# Html Simple Dom excluse TR rows based on TD text

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am a beginner so I am sorry for my question..

I have those code in use to scrape content from a website. This works as it is but I am searching for a way to only get the TR rows which DO not contain a certain value of text.

So what am i doing here. I find the table, within that table I get all the TR rows, I then need to find the input from all the TD rows but not from the TR rows that contains the value Chrysler ME412 (which is in one of the TD's). Than I get the name tag from the input I found and do something with it.

My problem. It finds all the TR rows, how do I find only the TR rows that do NOT contain the text value Chrysler ME412.

Does anyone know how to do this or has a link where to look as I cant find anything that helped so far.

```
//Gets all the TR rows from the table
    $tds = $html->find('table',3)->find('tr');
     
// One of those TD's in the TR contains this value. 
  

       if($tds->plaintext != 'Chrysler ME412'){
         foreach($tds as $td){
        // I only need it to find the input tag when the TR row does not contain the text Chrysler ME412 
        $ScrapedIdTopost = @$td->find('input');
        
        foreach ($ScrapedIdTopost as $PostID) {
        
        $PostIDStored =  @$PostID->name;
        $PostIDStoredInt =  @filter_var($PostID->name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $NameTag = "action".'['.$PostIDStoredInt.']';
    
        }
        
        
         }
```

Comment: you may want to try the [str_contains()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) function

and also move the if statement inside the foreach loop

Comment: Hey thanks. I did try that but it will still show the result I dont want. Do you have an example?